# PHP exploding array to array that has four cells

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I'm trying to explode my array to look like this:

```
[0] => Array
  (
      [0] => 14 // this is hours
      [1] => 38 // this is minutes
      [2] => 14 // this is hours again
      [3] => 59 // this is minutes again
  )
[1] => Array
  (
      [0] => 15 // this is hours
      [1] => 10 // this is minutes
      [2] => 16 // this is hours again
      [3] => 40 // this is minutes again
  )
  .
  .
  .
 [200] => Array
  (
      [0] => 13 // this is hours
      [1] => 35 // this is minutes
      [2] => 23 // this is hours again
      [3] => 32 // this is minutes again
  )
```

This because i will compare these times in the future.

I have list of times like this:

15:48,16:10
12:01,12:19
13:06,13:28
10:45,11:02

And now i got it in a array which looks like this:

```
[0] => 16:10,16:36
[1] => 13:06,13:17
.
.
.
[200] => 14:38,14:59
```

**What i have tried so far**

```
   $length = count($timesArr);
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
        foreach (explode(',', $timesArr[$i]) as $piece) {


            $timesArray[] = explode(':', $piece);
        }
     }
```

**and this is quite close because the result output is like this:**

```
   [0] => Array
    (
       [0] => 14
       [1] => 38
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
       [0] => 14
       [1] => 59
    )
```

**so again the main problem is that i need as seen above the cells 0 and 1 to be in the same cell**

I can also go for it straight from string so i would be exploding strings then.

Comment: You could use a regex with `preg_replace_callback()` to process it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution

```
$times = array( "16:10,16:36", '13:06,13:17');
$startendtimes = array();
foreach($times as $time){
    list($start,$end) = explode(',',$time);
    list($starthour,$startmin) = explode(':',$start);
    list($endhour,$endmin) = explode(':',$end);
    $startendtimes[] = array( $starthour,$startmin,$endhour,$endmin );

}
var_dump($startendtimes);
/* Outputs  
 array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '16' (length=2)
      1 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => string '16' (length=2)
      3 => string '36' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '13' (length=2)
      1 => string '06' (length=2)
      2 => string '13' (length=2)
      3 => string '17' (length=2)
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it. The simplest solution from your current position would be to use array_merge.

https://www.php.net/array_merge

If you pass in the first two (0 and 1) it will combine them into a single array.

Comment: Another possibility is to change how the string is stored in the first array.  If for example you were to replace all colons with commas before storing them in the $times[] then you would only have to do one explode() and no array_merge.  This is of course assuming that modifying the values stored in $times[] is acceptable in this particular project.

Comment: well i guess the array merge is not sufficient for this solution since the amount of these arrays changes depending on user file input. Anyway thanks for rapid answers! :)

Comment: What's the problem with it? You can pass in multiple arrays. It doesn't have to just be two.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_split('/[,:]/', $string)` should split the time string at both : and ,

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split()` should be sufficient
This works -

```
$timesArr = Array(
    "16:10,16:36",
    "13:06,13:17",
    "14:38,14:59"
);
foreach($timesArr as $time){
    $res[] = preg_split("/[\,\:]/",$time);
}
var_dump($res);
/*
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '16' (length=2)
      1 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => string '16' (length=2)
      3 => string '36' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '13' (length=2)
      1 => string '06' (length=2)
      2 => string '13' (length=2)
      3 => string '17' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '14' (length=2)
      1 => string '38' (length=2)
      2 => string '14' (length=2)
      3 => string '59' (length=2)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This easy, though `preg_split()` is cool:

```
$string = '15:48,16:10 12:01,12:19 13:06,13:28 10:45,11:02';

$array = array_chunk(explode(':', str_replace(array(',',' '), ':', $string)), 4);

print_r($array);
```